# ADFS and Anonymous access to path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7, adfs3.0

I have a web application that is configured to be secured by ADFS. And it works perfect. The only problem I have now, is that i need a particular path to be Anonymous.

Example:

myapp.com/services/api -> should be secured by adfs.

myapp.com/services/myPublicPath -> should not be secured by adfs.

I'm not very sure how to achieve that. I tried using location tag on web.config but not luck.. the entire site is secured by adfs.. i do not know how to create exceptions.

Here is my web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="oauth">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <runtime>
  </runtime>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <audienceUris>
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      </issuerNameRegistry>

      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>

  <system.identityModel.services>

    <federationConfiguration>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: The location tag normally works - what does yours look like?

Comment: @nzpcmad thanks. i added the web.config settings

Answer (score 0):

"myapp.com/services/myPublicPath -> should not be secured by adfs."

So the location should be something like:

```
<location path="services/myPublicPath "> 
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
```